# Ruby- read the value of a variable in another class?

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I have something like the following

```
class A 

  def initialize
    @var = 0
  end

  def dosomething
      @var+=1
  end

end

class B < A

 def initialize
   super
 end
 def func
    puts @var
 end
end
```

The problem is when I call

```
 a = A.new
 a.dosomething
 b = B.new
```

the value which `@var` returns is `0` how would I change my code so it would return the "new" value of var (1)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick answer, for if you actually understand Classes, Inheritance and Objects : replace `@var` (an instance variable, and therefore different in `a` and `b`) with `@@var` (a class variable, and therefore the same in all instances of `class A`).

Otherwise, your question indicates you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what's going on with classes, objects and inheritance.

Your code does the following:

- Defines a class, called `A`. This is essentially a blueprint from which you can create objects.

  - Declares that when an object of type `A` is created, that object should be given it's own private copy of an attribute, called `var`, which is set to `0`.
  - Declares that objects of type `A` can be asked to `dosomething`, which increases the value of that object's `var` by 1.
- Defines a class called `B`, which is a special case of an `A`

Therefore, in your second snippet, you create an object `a`, which is an `A`. It has its own attribute called `var`, which is set to 0 and then incremented. You then create `b`, which is a `B` (and is therefore also an `A`). `b` has *its own* attribute called `var`, *separate from* `a`'s `var`, which is set to 0.

Answer (score 2):

Variables like @var are called *instance variables* because they are unique to every instance of a class. You've created two separate instances, a and b, and they have their own instance variables.

You can use *class variables* if you want to see them in your subclass:

```
class A  
  @@var = 0 
  def dosomething 
    @@var += 1 
  end 
end 

class B < A 
 def func 
    puts @@var 
 end 
end
```

You can also use class-level accessor methods:

```
class A  
  class << self
    attr_accessor :var
    def dosomething(n) 
      self.var = n 
    end
  end 
end 

class B < A 
 def func 
    puts A.var 
 end 
end 

irb(main):031:0> A.dosomething(5)
=> 5
irb(main):032:0> b = B.new
=> #<B:0x2b349d>
irb(main):033:0> b.func
5
```

Note that inheritance is not needed for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

`@var` is an *instance variable*, each instance of this class has its own value of this variable. So it is correct that `b` does return 0, since it is a different instance compared to `a`.

To update the value in `b` use:

```
b = B.new
b.dosomething
```

[Here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Classes#Instance_Variables) is more information on instance variables.

*Or* if you want a *class variable* (ie a variable which is the same in **all** instances of that class), use `@@var`. Then your given example works.

[Here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Classes#Class_Variables) is some more information on class variables.

Which solution you need, depends on your application.

Answer (score 1):

You could use class variables:

```
class A 
  @@var = 0
  def dosomething
    @@var += 1
  end
end

class B < A
 def func
    puts @@var
 end
end

a = A.new
a.dosomething
a.dosomething
b = B.new
b.func # => 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use class variables, not instance variables. Try something like this:

```
class A

  @@var = 0

  def dosomething
      @@var+=1
  end
end

class B < A

 def func
    puts @@var
 end
end
```